# Is Teensy compatible with the Arduino keyboard library?

Tags: library, teensy, keyboard

I am thinking about buying some Teensy micro-controllers, but I want to know if the [teensy](https://www.adafruit.com/?q=teensy&) are compatible with the [arduino keyboard library.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Teensy designer uses the standard Arduino mouse and keyboard library:

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_keyboard.html

On another note, I'm sure Teensy is a fine product, but I prefer other open hardware solutions like Pro Micro which can be had on [AliExpress.com for  under $4 ea.](http://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-arduino-pro-micro.html?spm=2114.01010208.0.334.k7qlR1&site=glo&SearchText=arduino%20pro%20micro&g=y&SortType=price_asc&groupsort=1)